# Trace morphism for projective morphism on differentials forms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field, $X$ and $Y$ two connected $k$-varieties, and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ a dominant projective morphism of relative dimension $d$.

I would like to know under which condition there is a natural "trace" morphism
$$R^df_*\Omega_{X/Y}^d\rightarrow \mathcal O_Y,$$
which is not necessarily an isomorphism, but that it is an isomorphism on the smooth fibers (if they exist).

I think that if $f$ is l.c.i. morphism (which I might be okay to assume), then there is a dualizing sheaf $\omega_{X/Y}$ and a trace isomorphism
$$R^df_*\omega_{X/Y}\rightarrow \mathcal O_Y.$$

In this situation, what is the relation between $\omega_{X/Y}$ and $\Omega_{X/Y}^d$? Is there a morphism between them?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reasonable schemes, there is always a sheaf $\omega_{X/Y}$ and a canonical isomorphism
$$
\int_f \colon R^df_*\omega_{X/Y}\rightarrow \mathcal O_Y
$$
See the paper by Kleiman,

> Relative duality for quasicoherent sheaves Kleiman, Steven L.
> Compositio Math. 41 (1980), no. 1, 39–60. ([NUMDAM](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=CM_1980__41_1_39_0))

The morphism
$$
c_{X/Y} \colon \Omega_{X/Y}^d\rightarrow \omega_{X/Y} 
$$

is called the fundamental class. It is discussed in detail in the case that $X$ is an algebraic variety over $Y = \operatorname{Spec}(k)$ where $k$ is a perfect field in Lipman's "blue book":

> Dualizing sheaves, differentials and residues on algebraic varieties
> Lipman, Joseph Astérisque(1984), no. 117

In general, one uses the so called *fundamental class* in Hochschild homology. This is discussed in the paper (that uses the full machinery of Grothendieck duality and derived categories of sheaves)

> Bivariance, Grothendieck duality and Hochschild homology I:
> Construction of a bivariant theory
> Alonso-Tarrío, Leovigildo; Jeremías-López, Ana; Lipman, Joseph;
> Asian J. Math. 15 (2011), no. 3, 451–497.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I have just one further question: do you know how does the map H^1(X,\Omega^1_{X/k})---> k looks in some concrete situation? For example, I can image what is it if X is the union of two P^1, but I can't guess what the map does if X is a double line for example (i.e. x^2=0 inside P^2). Is it the composition of the map to the reduced part and the trace of this one?

Comment: Basically you take a Noether normalization $X \to P^1 \to \operatorname{Spec}(k)$ and then they integral on $X$ is the composition of the trace from $X$ to $P^1$ and the integral on $P^1$ that you can compute with Czech cocycles.